# Spring RepositoryRestResource response only if specific headers exist

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

How do i can specify `@RepositoryRestResource` enpoints to response only if mime-type is `application/json`?

example with `@RequestMapping`

GET-Request with `Accept : application/json` returns `json`

```
 @RequestMapping(path="/path", headers ="Accept=application/json")
    public String withHeader() {
        return  "{this:json}";
    }
```

GET-Request without `Accept : application/json` header returns `html`

```
@RequestMapping("/path" )
public String withoutHeader() {
    return  "<html>...</html>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make it out of the box. You need add a configuration like this

```
@Configuration
class RestMvcConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {

    return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.returnBodyOnUpdate("Accept=application/json")
        config.returnBodyOnCreate("Accept=application/json");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: This sets response media type to application/json. Correct? 
BUT I'm looking to ignore entire request if client is not capable to handle json. So Spring  RepositoryRest should response only if client represents Accept header with application/json!